# Not enough space in /boot, synaptic not working

Tags: boot

I'm trying to free up some space in my `/boot`, since a notification showed up that there was 0 bytes left. I used synaptic package manager, as I wasn't sure which package I should erase.
An error came up trying to remove the obsolete files, so it doesn’t seem to work.

Here is what is in my `/boot`:

```
abi-4.4.0-31-generic
memtest86+.bin
abi-4.4.0-59-generic
memtest86+.elf
abi-4.4.0-62-generic
memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-4.4.0-63-generic
System.map-4.4.0-31-generic
abi-4.4.0-64-generic
System.map-4.4.0-59-generic
abi-4.4.0-66-generic
System.map-4.4.0-62-generic
abi-4.4.0-70-generic
System.map-4.4.0-63-generic
abi-4.4.0-71-generic
System.map-4.4.0-64-generic
config-4.4.0-31-generic
System.map-4.4.0-66-generic
config-4.4.0-59-generic
System.map-4.4.0-70-generic
config-4.4.0-62-generic
System.map-4.4.0-71-generic
config-4.4.0-63-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
config-4.4.0-64-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic.efi.signed
config-4.4.0-66-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic
config-4.4.0-70-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic.efi.signed
config-4.4.0-71-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-62-generic
efi
vmlinuz-4.4.0-62-generic.efi.signed
grub
vmlinuz-4.4.0-63-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-63-generic.efi.signed
initrd.img-4.4.0-59-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-62-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic.efi.signed
initrd.img-4.4.0-63-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic.efi.signed
initrd.img-4.4.0-65-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-66-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic.efi.signed
initrd.img-4.4.0-70-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-71-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic.efi.signed
lost+found
```

Could you recommend a simple command line in the terminal to clean up some space?

Comment: Is your /boot a separate partition? if so can you extend it. You can clean up unused packages with sudo apt autoremove

Comment: Keep the currently running kernel listed in `uname -r`. Keep one older kernel. Uninstall the rest. If synaptic (and apt) don't work due to lack of space, then use dpkg to uninstall the first one.